# Angular navigate to component by full page load

Tags: angular

I am new to Angular and stuck with the following problem:

I have a login component from which I to move to dashboard component when login is correct.

I am trying to import css in dashboard component but they are not loading. But, if I reload the page, the styles are applied.
In dashboard.css file, I have imports like this:

```
@import 'src/assets/css/style.css';
```

So, I think, when I move from login to dashboard component, I need to fully load the page instead of simply moving to dashboard component with **router-outlet**.

So, what is the best way to navigate to dashboard component and all imports are applied?

I tried following but they don't load the page fully:

```
this.router.navigateByUrl('/dashboard');
```

or

```
this.router.navigate(['dashboard']);
```

I think I'll need something like this:

```
  this->window.location = '...';
```

I'll try to find if similar statement exists in Angular

Comment: these both 2 ways do render the component to the router-outlet

Answer (score 2):

I figured out, this is the statement I need to use:

```
  window.location.href = 'dashboard';
```